# convert HTMLCollection to Array by ID

Tags: arrays, xml, loops, htmlcollection

I got a big problem with creating XML to send. All I have is HTML Nodes connected with specially built ID with schema: _header_firstLeveL_secondLevel_anotherLevel

HTML structure:

```
<input id="_movies_noGenre_documents_AnInconvenientTruth" type="text" value="A">
<input id="_movies_genre_horror_blackAndWhite_Saw" type="text" value="B">
<input id="_movies_genre_horror_blackAndWhite_Dracula" type="text" value="C">
<input id="_movies_genre_horror_color_It" type="text" value="D">
<input id="_movies_genre_comedy_blackAndWhite_DuckSoap" type="text" value="E">
<input id="_movies_genre_comedy_color_Hangover" type="text" value="F">
<input id="_movies_genre_comedy_color_Superbad" type="text" value="G">
<input id="_movies_genre_comedy_color_Anchorman" type="text" value="H">
```

and target object:

```
var object = [
    movies : {
        noGenre : {
            documents : {
                AnInconvenientTruth : A
            }
        },
        genre: {
            horror : {
                blackAndWhite : {
                    Saw : B,
                    Dracula : C
                },
                color : {
                    It : D
                }
            },
            comedy : {
                blackAndWhite : {
                    DuckSoap : E
                },
                color : {
                    Hangover : F,
                    Superbad : G,
                    Anchorman : H
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

All this because later i got to iterate through this object and prepare string to build a XML to send.

Thank you in advance for ideas!

Comment: so where is your xml? you want to create javascript object or xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery for parsing the html

```
var object = {}
$("input").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var id_parts = id.split("_");
      var tmp_obj  = object;
      for (var i=0; i<id_parts.length -1; i++) {
             if (!tmp_obj[id_parts[i]])
                  tmp_obj[id_parts[i]] = {};
             tmp_obj = tmp_obj[id_parts[i]];
      }
      tmp_obj[id_parts[id_parts.length -1]]=$(this).val();
});
```

try this, i hope this would help you.

Comment: Emech You saved my life! :-) Can You explain me a little bit how it works? In speciall var tmp_obj  = object part, please.

Comment: you have a nested attributes, separated by underline. you can use recursive function or some thing like I did. for each input element i'd separated the keys then for each key i checked if "object" has the key so i'll go for next nested attribute. in "var tmp_obj = object" our tmp_obj is the same as object not a copy of it, so every change in it will be save to object variable. in java script you can use an attribute by "object.key" or object["key"] so i used the second for dynamic attributes separated by "_".